# Which is the correct way to register a new net_device?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

i'm trying to register a new `net_device` in linux...i can alloc and register it correctly and `ifconfig` shows it. The problem arrives when i try to put the interface up:

```
ifconfig my_dev up
```

A kernel freeze occurs...the problem is present only on x86 machines and i can't figure out the reason...on a pcc machine all works well. The code is very simple:

```c
static struct net_device *my_dev;

static int veth_dev_init(struct net_device *dev);
static int veth_open(struct net_device *dev);
static int veth_close(struct net_device *dev);
static int veth_ioctl(struct net_device *dev, struct ifreq *ifr, int cmd);

static struct veth_priv
{
   ...
};

static struct net_device_ops veth_ops =
{
  .ndo_init = veth_dev_init,
  .ndo_open = veth_open,
  .ndo_stop = veth_close,
  .ndo_do_ioctl = veth_ioctl
};

static int __init veth_init()
{
  my_dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof(struct veth_priv), "my_dev", ether_setup);
  if (my_dev == NULL)
    return -ENOMEM;

  my_dev->netdev_ops = &veth_ops;

  register_netdev(my_dev);
  return 0;
}

static void __exit veth_exit()
{
  unregister_netdev(my_dev);
  free_netdev(my_dev);
}

module_init(veth_init);
module_exit(veth_exit);
```

The first four functions `veth_dev_init, veth_open, veth_close` and `veth_ioctl` simply return 0.
Maybe is there a missing field in `veth_ops` structure?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yea, you missed one element in **struct net_device_ops**

Add **.ndo_start_xmit** also, And the function must return NETDEV_TX_OK or NETDEV_TX_BUSY.

use as follows

```
static netdev_tx_t veth_xmit(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev)
{
    return NETDEV_TX_OK;
}
```

And also change the **open** as

```
static int veth_open(struct net_device *dev)
{
     memcpy(dev->dev_addr, "\0ABCD0", ETH_ALEN);
     netif_start_queue(dev);
     return 0;
}
```

Then in **veth_ops**

```
static struct net_device_ops veth_ops = {
     .ndo_init         = veth_dev_init,
     .ndo_open         = veth_open,
     .ndo_stop         = veth_close,
     .ndo_start_xmit   = veth_xmit,
     .ndo_do_ioctl     = veth_ioctl,
};
```

Then after inserting the module

give ifconfig my_dev 192.168.10.98 ...

Comment: Thanks Faisal, it works! But i can't undestand the reason...why the system should call the function `dev->netdev_ops->ndo_start_xmit` when i put up my interface?

Comment: The example version of `veth_xmit` should probably also call `consume_skb(skb)`.

Comment: If ipv4 is enabled, the system may send out an arp request for your ip, to see if there is a conflict on the local lan. For IPv6, the system may do neighbor discovery. I generally find that there are around ~30 packets that leave when I bring up an interface.

Comment: Ah ok! It makes sense!Maybe all works on a ppc system depending only on the fact that system doesn't send those packets...Thank you sharth!