# What does dev_net_set do in Linux?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a simple net device driver based on the loopback driver and want to register my `net_device` structure. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726939/) and [that](http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/e4022/code/drivers/Kernel/docs.html) page on writing a net device say to just call `register_netdev`. But they're writing fancy drivers with PCI express and other complicated things.

So, if I just want something like the loopback driver, I should presumably base my code on `loopback.c`. My question is, what does the first line of this code in `loopback_net_init` do:

```
dev_net_set(dev, net);
err = register_netdev(dev);
```

Apparently `net` is determined by this code in `net_namespace.c`:

```
register_pernet_device(ops) ...
__register_pernet_operations(list, ops)
   for_each_net(net) ...
```

What is this looping for? What might go wrong if I skip the `dev_net_set` call? Why are others not using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html

> A network namespace is logically another copy of the network stack,
>   with its own routes, firewall rules, and network devices.

So `for_each_net` is looping over these namespaces and creating a copy of all "per net" network devices in each one.

Use `ip netns list` to determine whether you are using network namespaces. Often they are not used, so drivers do not necessarily need to use `dev_net_set`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, net is a structure that will allow the kernel to interact with the device. You need it to register the device and remove it in the module cleanup function. Please review the code under linux/net/8021q/ for examples.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, looping happens at the level of sockets (layer 5-7), whereas net_dev is used as the kernel component that immediately interacts with the driver, when you actually want to use a say, ethernet card, or SLIP,PLIP for transmitting frames (layer 2-0). Loopback happens at the level of the network subsystem of the kernel, and lies way above the drivers which interact with the hardware. So I don't see why you would need a driver to use the loopback feature. However, there is also a provision for registering a dummy device with net_dev, though I don't know if that is what you are looking for.

That said, if your intention is to simply use some driver that simulates an actual physical device without one and say, reflects the packets that it recieves, that is possible too. Basically till the net_dev layer, the kernel does all the protocol stuff (TCP/IP), and finally passes off the packet to some handle that the device driver registers with the net_dev or something similar. Similarly on receiving stuff, the device triggers an interrupt, the driver does a DMA operation, and the kernel takes over from there. Hence instead of the code for doing the DMA operation, you can make a module that simply pass over a static packet, that is compatible with ethernet/TCP/IP .  In a vast majority of cases, all these aspects (the network and other subsystems) are agnostic to the underlying bus details, i.e. it shouldn't matter whether the ethernet card is connected to PCI or ISA but there can be exceptions. Thus, IMHO, you are trying to do something that should only be attempted after having a thorough understanding of the network subsystem, and a good enough understanding of the kernel as a whole. Till then you will be shooting in the dark. Sometimes you may hit, but often-times you will miss.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand the kernel and network subsystem, so that my driver behaves as expected, and I'm writing a loopback-like driver, so I don't care about PCI etc. Good observations. However, I don't see how `for_each_net` can possibly pertain to L5+. It is calling `register_netdev` on multiple things, so it is managing multiple L2s, so if anything it must be something *below* L2.

Comment: Yes, all the net_dev related stuff, are L2-L0. See, loop-back is the name for a functionality, where the packets simply bounce back to the host system, rather than be sent to another host. That functionality is most easily implemented at the level of sockets (L5+). However, it is just as possible to bypass that, make the data go through all the protocol (TCP/IP) (L5-L2), send it to a dummy device/driver (L2-L0), and make that driver, send back that packet to the host device in some appropriate manner. Of course, the tutorial is meant to teach students the (L2-L0) network stack details.